# Issue with contenteditable property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am adding `contenteditable` property on each div with class `.edit` :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".edit").attr("contenteditable", "true");
});
```

Now after this when i click over the `div` whose `contenteditable="true"` i am not able to edit but when i `rightclick` over that `div` then it shows `cursor to edit` but then `spacebar` and `arrow keys` are not working.

In my code there are other things are also applied on the `div with class edit` like `draggable`, `resizable` and lots of other events like `mouseenter`, `mouseleave` etc. I know my question does`nt contain sufficient information but i am posting it in hope that may someone have already face this issue and have solution. Thanks :)

Comment: It is working for me see: http://jsfiddle.net/msy8U/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".edit").prop("contentEditable", "true"); // Note the capital E
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below Code,

```
 $(".edit").attr("contenteditable", "true").foucs();
```